# How safe is upgrading java version for Cloudera?

Tags: java, hadoop, cloudera

I have a cloudera cluster running  Cloudera Standard 4.7.3 and CDH 4.5 with Java 1.6.

according to the [Cloudera Documetation](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CDH4/latest/CDH4-Requirements-and-Supported-Versions/cdhrsv_topic_3.html) these versions support java 1.7.

I want to know if this upgrade is safe, or if there are potential problems with it?

Comment: This is a question for serverfault.com, not SO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We upgraded our cluster to java 1.7 and didn't have any problems neither with M/R jobs nor Hive jobs

Answer (score 2):

It is safe to use any supported version of Java with CDH. You can safely use it with the versions of Java 7 you see have been tested. Of course, you need to run the same version of Java across your cluster.

Unsupported versions likely work fine too, but is not guaranteed.

Comment: and is just stopping the cluster and upgrading the JDK a safe procedure?
The alternative it to install a test cluster, and verify the installation procedure - but this would be very time consuming.

Comment: I don't know of a reason it would not be safe, but I'm not one of our support experts. If it matters, I'd consult Cloudera support about the best procedure.